# Duplicity/Duply Backup of EFS filesystem on AWS: All files "possibly locked"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, backup, duplicity

I have an EFS file-system on AWS being mounted by an EC2 instance in order to perform backups.  The filesystem has appropriate permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

The ec2 instance is running duplicity/duply to backup EFS to an S3 bucket.  The first time the backup ran without any issues.  Now, every time it runs via cron I am getting this error for every file, and therefore duplicity is never completing backups:

```
Error accessing possibly locked file
```

Is this a problem with duplicity?  How do I correct this?

*Edit - I can manually copy files off EFS with no problems using the same user duplicity is running under.

The filesystem is mounted under /home/user/efs. A `lsof` one of the locked files outputs nothing.

Comment: Can you work out what file it's referring to? From there you could probably do some diagnostics. It could be as simple as a log file locked for writing.

Comment: EFS imposes finite limits on the number of concurrently-lockable files. [*"Each unique mount on the instance can acquire up to a total of 8,192 locks across a maximum of 256 unique file/process pairs."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html) The first limit reached is the one that applies.  It's not clear whether this may be relevant but it's something I encountered in a configuration that did not involve duplicity.

Comment: It looks like -- possibly -- `lsof` can be used to identify the source of locks on files. Likely that would only help if the locks are held by the same machine.  Are other machines able to access the EFS filesystem?  What kind of workload are you running?  Have you tried increasing the duplicity log level, e.g. `--verbosity 9`?

Comment: Tim - I guess I'm not quite certain what you are asking.  Duplicity seems to be claiming almost all of the files are locked.  Are you saying diagnose based on one of the locked files?

Comment: Michael - I'll try both of those and see if I can get some more information.  The EFS filesystem is being used by multiple machines, but writes should be fairly limited during the time when I am trying to run backups.